# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP while apache working

Tags: mysql, xampp, shutdown

This message is in my XAMPP control panel when I click the start button.
This warning is showing that MySQL shutdown unexpectedly, but the Apache Server is running fine.

```
11:29:21 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
11:29:21 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
11:29:28 AM  [main]     Executing "c:\xampp\mysql"
11:29:50 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
11:29:51 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:30:00 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

This is MySQL error log:

```
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 113908; transaction id 9
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200505 11:29:51
2020-05-05 11:29:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I tried most of the things I found on StackOverflow, but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this helpful after searching for nearly an hour online. 
[image: MySQLErrorFix] 
You can go through the [solution screenshotted here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=79154) or browse the [XAMPP forum here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewforum.php?f=16)

Comment: Worked! What is this actually doing?

Answer (score 8):

This method solved solved my issues

Step 1. Rename the folder c:\xampp\mysql\data to c:\xampp\mysql\data_old (you can use any name).

Step 2. Create a new folder c:\xampp\mysql/data.

Step 3. Copy the content that resides in mysql\backup to the new mysql\data folder.

Step 4. Copy all your database folders that are in mysql\data_old to mysql\data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old).

Step 5. Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql\data_old and replace it inside mysql\data folder.

Step 6. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel.

And, Its DONE . No databases lost, no ports changed, no run as administrator, no force recovery, no kill mysqld process, no restoring from previous versions, no more errors.

For more information check this [blog post](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue that I faced is, some of my **database size is to high**.
But ibdata1 can not be auto extended.
So I did those step and my error was fixed.

1. Go to **mysql/data** folder
2. remove `aria_log.00000001, aria_log_control, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, mysql.pid`
3. Go to the my.ini from **mysql/bin**
4. Here you will find some buffer size related key values like->
   `key_buffer,  max_allowed_packet,  sort_buffer_size,  net_buffer_length,  read_buffer_size,  read_rnd_buffer_size,  myisam_sort_buffer_size,  innodb_data_file_path,  innodb_buffer_pool_size,  innodb_log_file_size,  innodb_log_buffer_size,  innodb_lock_wait_timeout,  max_allowed_packet`
5. restart apache and mysql

check if it is solved or not.
**100%** worked for me.